# Use HikariDatasource or DB specific datasources

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

Hi I use spring boot and I need datasource to connect different databases.
For example to connect  SqlServer ,microsoft provide com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc and this jar has SqlServerDatasource but when I checked details this datasource doesnt have pooling mechanism.

I can use hikaridatasource to connect different databases and hikaridatasource has connection pooling mechanism

My question is which is the best practice to use hikaridatasource or sqlserverdatasource, oracledatasource to connect databases specific datasource  in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `java.sql.DataSource` interface and not expose the implementation to my application.